# How to iterate environment variables in ansible?

Tags: postgresql, loops, ansible, environment-variables, host

In this playbook

```
# db.yml

- hosts: deploy-server
  become: True
  roles:
    - db
  environment:
    PGHOST: "{{ db_host }}"
    PGPASSWORD: "{{ db_pass }}"
```

In db roles

```
# roles/db/tasks/main.yml

- name: Run sql
  shell: "psql -U postgres -f /sql"
```

I want to deploy the same sql script to multiple db servers.

For example, use these variables:

- db_host1
- db_host2
- ...

Not by ssh but using psql. So is it possible to loop the `PGHOST` variable to set dynamic list to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: *"**Is it possible to loop the PGHOST variable?**"*

A: Yes. It is possible. Set the environment variable in the loop, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - command: "echo $PGHOST"
      register: result
      loop: [db_host1, db_host2]
      environment:
        PGHOST: "{{ item }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.results|json_query('[].stdout') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - db_host1
  - db_host2
```

---

If you want to apply various environment to a role iterate [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#ansible-builtin-include-role-load-and-execute-a-role) and [apply](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#parameter-apply) the environment, e.g. the role

```yaml
shell> cat roles/db/tasks/main.yml 
- command: "echo $PGHOST"
  register: result
- debug:
    var: result.stdout
```

and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: db
        apply:
          environment:
            PGHOST: "{{ item }}"
      loop: [db_host1, db_host2]
```

give

```yaml
...

TASK [include_role : db] ***********************************************

TASK [db : command] ****************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [db : debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  result.stdout: db_host1

TASK [db : command] ****************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [db : debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  result.stdout: db_host2

...
```